# Better spell Checker (german language)

Tags: spell-checking

Most spell checkers are very simple. They check if the word is a valid word.

I want a better spell checkers for the german language which can check the sentence, not just each single word.

I am happy with a commercial app, does not need to be open source.

Does anyone know such a spell checker for ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

For Libre Office you may use Language tool extension.You can take it from Libre site: http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/languagetool